# Fingerprint Scar/Crease region detection

Tags: fingerprint

Can anyone suggest me a good method to detect fingerprint scar region detection. I need the region where the scars are present in fingerprint image. Scar can be in any direction (Horizontal/vertical or any other direction). Valley part of the fingerprint should not be considered as scar. Basically a scar will be of more thickness than valley region.

I am trying to find out the scar in the following image .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Dif.png)

So if any one can suggest a good method to differentiate these scars from valley than plz help me.

Comment: Check if this documentation about SourceAFIS here www.sourceafis.org/blog/fingerprint-recognition-sdk-review/ will be of help to you.